# Getting input in dcoder in r language

Tags: r

[image]

I am working on dcoder in r language. However, I cannot get the second line of input. I tried readLines("stdin", n=1) but only get the first line. The second line always get charater(0). How should I get the second line of input?

Result

Input:

2

80 80

70 60

Output:

[1] "2"

character(0)

Comment: What happens if you simply use readLines()?

Comment: @AndersEllernBilgrau
It get stuck.

I tried 5 cases with same input:

input: 
2
80 80
70 60
 

1.
num <- readLines()
print(num)

output: 
no output


2.
print("hey")
num <- readLines()
print(num)

output: 
[1] "hey"


3.
num <- readLines("stdin", n=1)
print(num)
temp <- readLines()
print(temp)

output:
[1] 2


4.
num <- readLines()
print(num)
temp <- readLines("stdin", n=1)
print(temp)

output:
no output


5.
print("hey")
num <- readLines()
print(num)
print("end")

output:
[1] "hey"

Comment: I am new to here, sorry for the format  
input:<br/>
2<br/>
80 80<br/>
70 60<br/>
<br/>
1. <br/>
num <- readLines() <br/>
print(num) <br/>
output:<br/>
no output<br/>
<br/>
2.<br/>
print("hey")<br/>
num <- readLines()<br/>
print(num)<br/>
output:<br/>
[1] "hey"<br/>
<br/>
3.<br/>
num <- readLines("stdin", n=1)<br/>
print(num)<br/>
temp <- readLines()<br/>
print(temp)<br/>
output:<br/>
[1] 2<br/>
<br/>
4. <br>
num <- readLines()<br/>
print(num)<br/>
temp <- readLines("stdin", n=1)<br/>
print(temp)<br/>
output:<br/>
no output<br/>
<br/>